# Why is this not the same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my test I assure that two controller methods are called in a seperate helper class:

```
controller.expects(:sign_in).with(user).returns(:ok)
controller.expects(:redirect_to).returns(:ok)
```

When my write my helper class like, that, **the tests work as aspected and succeed**:

```
  def call
    @controller = context.controller

    controller.sign_in user
    controller.redirect_to remove_from_url(url)
  end
```

But when I change it to:

```
  def call
    @controller = context.controller

    controller do
      sign_in user
      redirect_to remove_from_url(url)
    end
  end
```

**Then the tests fail**, as message I get:

```
expected exactly once, not yet invoked ...
```

**Why does this code not do the same?**Thanks

```
1)  controller.sign_in user
    controller.redirect_to remove_from_url(url)

2)  controller do
      sign_in user
      redirect_to remove_from_url(url)
    end
```

Comment: I guess the block version uses `send` or `public_send` under the hood, whereas the first version calls the method directly.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks, how would you change that code?

Comment: Why don't you want to use your first version? It seems to work as aspected and it looks fine.